# How could I use the regex Branch Reset Group in Java with Netbeans

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I wrote a regular expression to use in my Java application. In it I used the  branch reset group modifier `(?|...)`. When I started the application and tried to match that regex i got the `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index` error. On that index is my `?|` modifier. 
After some research I found out that Java does not support that modifier, but some other languages do. Is there a way for me to add some other library to my Netbeans project that supports the expression or is it a problem with Java? Or is there a simple alternative to the modifier? I'm not really sure how that works but I can't seem to find much information on the internet about it.

Comment: It is an XY problem. Java regex does not support branch reset, and almost no regex supports it but PCRE and its related regex libraries. You can't use it in Java.

Comment: So there isn't a library in Java that I can install to use it?

Comment: No idea, I could only find https://github.com/raimonbosch/java.pcre, but it looks very old.

Answer (score -1):

I personaly don't use Netbeans and i don't know any library supporting it but i solved a similar problem by using a simple "match a or b" group.
`(?:FirstOption|SecondOption|...)`

Comment: Hmm that could usually work yes, but in my case I have something like `(?:FirstOption|SecondOption FirstParameter|ThirdOption SecondParameter|...)` and in this example i would have a group that contains either `FirstOption` or `ThirdOption SecondParameter`, but i want the parameters in a seperate group, but with the same index/name.

Comment: Did you try using a positive Lookahead?

Comment: No, not yet. First I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to use the modifier in question. If it can't I'll do some research about alternatives, like maybe doing it with the positive lookahead.